# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare wc_get_container()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to make a custom plugin, which will work with woocommerce.
that is why i included woocommerce in my plugin with the help of this line of code

include(WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/woocommerce/woocommerce.php');

But I can not active my custom plugin. in the time of activating it says
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare wc_get_container() (previously declared in /home/eteasnzs/mshopbd.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php:58) in /home/eteasnzs/mshopbd.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php on line 58

I did a little google and show there are several fatal errors like this function already declared..

Now my question is how can I solve this type of problem..
thanks and this my first question here... hope I will get a helpful solution....

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like that file is being included multiple times, in which case you just need to change

```
include(WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/woocommerce/woocommerce.php');
```

to

```
include_once(WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/woocommerce/woocommerce.php');
```

> The [`include_once`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) statement includes and evaluates the specified file during the execution of the script. This is a behavior similar to the include statement, with the only difference being that if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again, and include_once returns true. As the name suggests, the file will be included just once.